# Origin of use of "quotient" to describe structures induced by equivalence classes

Tags: mathematics, terminology, language

I'm sure this question has been asked somewhere, but I have been unable to find it. Why is it that when we have some set $X$ with an equivalence relation $\equiv$, and $X$ has some structure (e.g. a group operation, a topology, a vector space), we refer to the structure induced by $\equiv$ on $X / \equiv$ a "quotient" (group, topology, vector space, etc.). My guess would be that it comes from a prior use of "quotient" to talk about division on $\mathbb{R}$, and so the field of fractions on $\mathbb{Z}$ (with an equivalence relation in the from of $x / y \equiv ax / ay$) was the source of using "quotient". Is this correct? If not, what is the origin behind referring to the induced structure as a "quotient"?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the origin is with the theory of groups: see [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group#Motivation_for_the_name_.22quotient.22).

According to [William Burnside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Burnside) in:

- [Theory of groups of finite order](https://archive.org/details/theorygroupsfin00burngoog) (1897), page 38:

> Herr [Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_H%C3%B6lder) [*footnote*:  ["Zurückführung einer beliebigen algebraischen Gleichung auf eine Kette von Gleichungen"](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0034&DMDID=DMDLOG_0008), *Math.Ann.*,‎ 1889] has introduced the symbol
>
> $$\dfrac G \Gamma$$
>
> to represent this group; he calls it the *quotient* of $G$ by $\Gamma$ and a *factor-group* of $G$.

Comment: I think first vague attempt made by A. Cayley in 1893.  [Note on the So-Called Quotient G/H in the Theory of Groups](https://doi.org/10.2307/2369521)